# Ember, Rails, Amazon S3 image not loading issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, amazon-s3, carrierwave

I have an app that has two models Image and Project. An image belongs to a project and a project has many images.

I previously had it setup so that images were stored locally and everything was working fine but as Heroku doesn't support local storage of uploaded files I have setup an Amazon S3 bucket to handle the image storage.

The issue I am having is that on my projects page the first image of a project should be displayed but it isn't loading or showing any errors.

#### Models are as follows:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/models/project.js

App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  client: DS.attr('string'),
  tags: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  start_date: DS.attr('string'),
  end_date: DS.attr('string'),

  images: DS.hasMany('image', {async: true}),

  projectDuration: function() {
    return this.get('start_date') + ' to ' + this.get('end_date')
  }.property('start_date', 'end_date'),

  firstImage: function() {
    var projectImages = this.get('images');
    var projectImage = projectImages.get('firstObject');
    return projectImage;
  }.property('images')

});

#app/assets/javascripts/models/image.js

App.Image = DS.Model.extend({
  _project_image: DS.attr('string'),
  _project_id: DS.attr('number'),


  project: DS.belongsTo('project')
});
```

#### Store.js

```
#app/assets/javascripts/store.js

DS.RESTAdapter.reopen({
  namespace: 'api/v1'
})

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({});
App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.ActiveModelAdapter.extend({});
```

#### Template

```
#app/assets/javascripts/templates/projects.js.emblem

section
  .container
    .row
      .col-xs-12.col-sm-10.col-sm-offset-1.col-md-8.col-md-offset-2
        .row
          each project in controller
            link-to 'project' project
              .col-xs-12
                img.transition src=project.firstImage._project_image 
                h1.text-center.text-uppercase = project.client
                p.subtext.text-center = project.tags
```

#### Serializers

```
#app/serializers/image_serializer.rb

class ImageSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  attributes :id, :_project_image, :_project_id
  def _project_image
    object.project_image.to_s
  end

  def _project_id
    object.project_id.to_i
  end
end

#app/serializers/project_serializer.rb

class ProjectSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  attributes :id, :name, :client, :tags, :description, :start_date, :end_date
  has_many :images, embed: :ids, include: true

end
```

When using local storage I didn't include `{async: true}` in my project model but this creates an error that says:

`You looked up the 'images' relationship on '<App.Project:ember356:9>' but some of the associated records were not loaded. Either make sure they are all loaded together with the parent record, or specify that the relationship is async (`DS.hasMany({ async: true })`)`

But then I specify `{async: true}` and my images won't load on the projects template.

They do however still load in my project template.

Answer (score 0):

I have just worked this out!

It turns out you need to specifically state the async relationship as either true of false - not remove the option altogether.

I ended up with:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/models/project.js
App.Project = DS.Model.extend({
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  client: DS.attr('string'),
  tags: DS.attr('string'),
  description: DS.attr('string'),
  start_date: DS.attr('string'),
  end_date: DS.attr('string'),

  images: DS.hasMany('image', {async: false}),

  projectDuration: function() {
    return this.get('start_date') + ' to ' + this.get('end_date')
  }.property('start_date', 'end_date'),

  firstImage: function() {
    var projectImages = this.get('images');
    var projectImage = projectImages.get('firstObject');
    return projectImage;
  }.property('images')

});
```